Can you use async await safely inside an async void event handler in c#?
I have an async void event handler that must stay "fire-and-forget". Sadly, it contains logic that may throw an exception. I was thinking of putting the actual business logic inside an async Task that is awaited inside the async void HandleMessageSafely() method that only has the responsibility of catching and logging errors.
The HandleMessage method may be overridden by subclasses of Example.MessageHandler
I'm not asking if this is good design (I assume it's not), but if it is safe, and does not interfere with my "fire and forget" requirements. To me this solution seems pretty straight forward, but I didn't find any similar examples on the net and I am afraid that I am missing something. Bonus points for a "nice" solution.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Example.MessageHandler;

public class MessageHandler<TMessage>
{
    protected async Task HandleMessage(TMessage mEvent)
    {
        // some async logic that needs await but may throw an exception
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }

    public async void HandleMessageSafely(TMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            await HandleMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uncaught exception");
        }
    }
}


Define "safe". If you do it tthis way, at least exceptions will be logged. But that's about it. What else would you desire to happen if one of tthose operations fail?

That's basically everything. The sub handlers we'll implement actually should not throw exceptions anyways, but we need an extra safety measure to not crash the application if anything goes wrong. in short: if some events get lost, that's ok, but if the app crashes, that's bad

So then what's your question?  Are you wondering if HandleMessageSafely can actually throw an exception, are you expecting people to tell you that what you want to happen isn't actually a good idea, or what?

There needs to be a very compelling reason to use async void, but yes: what you have is "safe" in terms of it won't break the runtime or kill the process

isn't there a global exception handler for your application type that you can subscribe to? The way the c# compiler generates async void it helps post the exceptions on the captutred SynchronizationContext.

also what exactly are the fire-and-forget requirements?

A lot of these kinds of design questions are best answered by removing async, thinking about the answer, and then adding async back in.
In this case, "I have an event handler that cannot throw exceptions (it must avoid application crashes), but the business logic may throw exceptions." Would this be an acceptable pattern in that case?
public class MessageHandler<TMessage>
{
    protected void HandleMessage(TMessage mEvent)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }

    public void HandleMessageSafely(TMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            HandleMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uncaught exception");
        }
    }
}

If this is an acceptable pattern, then the async equivalent is also acceptable. As far as the code structure itself goes, it seems ok.
Most of the time, I avoid "try to keep the app from crashing" (i.e., "catch all exceptions and keep going") code, because the business logic bugs then end up either 1) corrupting state (including possibly losing user data), and/or 2) not notifying the user (appears to no-op, or maybe the user thinks it did something when it didn't). For more thoughts on this design philosophy, Google "let it crash".
However, if this is acceptable for your use case, then the async equivalent is also acceptable.
